# How does order attribute in django models determines the ordering of fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The questions seems silly on first reading. I know. I came across some models where an attribute 'order' which is just an IntegerField determines the ordering on the frontend. Example model:

```
class FilterGroup(models.Model):
    """
    A way to group different kinds of filters from each other.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True,
                            help_text='the slug to be used as the name of the '
                                      'query parameter in the search URL')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                help_text='An integer defining which order '
                                          'the filter group should show up '
                                          'in the sidebar')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-order', 'name')
        unique_together = (
            ('name', 'slug'),
        )
```

There are three filter groups. Documents, Skill Level and Topics. They are rendered in the order: 'Topics', 'Skill level', 'Documents' which is not alphabetical. According to the help text, order determines the ordering of fields. I understand that Meta ordering suggests its ascending by name and descending by 'order'. Since the value of order is 1, How does it render like it does. This is the serializers snippet:

```
for group_options, filters in filter_groups.items():
            group_name, group_slug, group_order = group_options
            sorted_filters = sorted(filters, key=attrgetter('name'))
            grouped_filters.append(FilterGroup(name=group_name,
                                               slug=group_slug,
                                               order=group_order,
                                               options=sorted_filters))
        return FacetedFilterSerializer(
            sorted(grouped_filters, key=attrgetter('order')),
            many=True
        ).data
```

Its being sorted by getting the 'order' attribute. I don't understand the reason behind the order of rendering Filter Groups is an Integer value of 1

Comment: I am not sure about what do you want to do exactly, could you be more specific about what you don't understand about ordering? May are you looking for order_by() for queries? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

Comment: Have you verified a pure query of the ```FilterGroup``` returns them in the order you showed? You can test this in the shell. I could see the ```sorted``` call causing it to sort them in a way you don't expect since you don't specify ```name``` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Meta.ordering` property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#ordering) defines the default order of objects when they are retrieved using querysets in Django.  It is roughly equivalent to calling `Model.objects.order_by(Model.Meta.ordering)` every time you call `Model.objects`, which means that you can also override it by [calling `order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) on any queryset.

In your case, you are not actually using a queryset to build the list of `FilterGroup` objects, so `Meta.ordering` does not actually come into play. You are manually overriding the sorting in your final call to `sorted`, which is actually doing the equivalent of `.order_by("order")` and is the opposite of what you have set in your `Meta.ordering`.